# Is Date Between Two Dates SharePoint

Tags: date, sharepoint

I have a list that tracks activity for my team. Everyone puts their information in with a Start Date and Due Date. On the first day of every month I pull a report to see what was accomplished in the previous month. Nothing is ever deleted from the list so there are activities from a year ago in there. I would like to export a report of only activities from the previous month. I have tried to create a view for this and another column that would populate yes or no depending on whether the last month fell between the start and end date but neither worked.

ex. for the month of September YES indicates I want it in the report, NO I do not want it in the report

```
Case 1: Start Date = 9/2/16, Due Date = 9/30/16, YES
Case 2: Start Date = 9/16/16, Due Date = 10/5/16, YES
Case 3: Start Date = 8/7/16, Due Date = 9/14/16, YES
Case 4: Start Date = 6/6/16, Due Date = 7/7/16, NO
Case 5: Start Date = 10/1/16, Due Date = 10/12/16, NO
```

The calculated column I tried to create as a quick fix for looked like this

```
=IF(OR([Start Date]>=9/1/16,[Due Date]>=9/1/16),"YES","NO")
```

I then planned to filter it on YES. I know that's not a good code for the long run but I am by no means a SharePoint expert so I was just trying to figure something out as a sort of band aid.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code above Is that you will need to update your formula everytime you want to use the view.

You want a formula similar to the one below so on the first of every month it should relate correctly

```
=IF(OR((MONTH([Due Date])=MONTH(TODAY())-1),(MONTH([Start Date])=MONTH(TODAY())-1)),"YES","NO")
```

Cheers

Truez

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to do that as well but unfortunately SharePoint doesn't allow you to use TODAY in calculated fields.